# Node.js - GCP - Cloud Functions - VM disk snapshot across all regions and VMs

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I would like to use GCP serverless - Cloud Functions to backup the VM disks across all regions,

Basically - I want to backup all the VM disks with time-stamped snapshot name like snapshot-vm_name-timestamp

any backup older than 14 days, delete it. So that this is self serve function.

The documentation sucks and is of not much help. This is how far i could get

```
exports.run_process = (req, res) => {
  let message = req.query.message || req.body.message || 'Hello World!';

  console.log(message);

  const Compute = require(`@google-cloud/compute`);
  const compute = new Compute();
  const zone = compute.zone('us-east1-b');

  zone.getDisks(function(err, disks) {
    // `disks` is an array of `Disk` objects.
    disks.map(disk => {
      console.log(disk);
    });
  });

  res.status(200).send(message);
};
```

any help or advice is much appreciated.

reference link : https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.10.x/Zone

Comment: Have you seen this API which appears to create a snapshot?  https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.10.x/Disk#createSnapshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an error in your code. Where you are using the `const Compute = require(@google-cloud/compute);` statement. Instead of " **`** " you have to use " **'** ". Also, remember to use the library you need to add dependencies. Your `package.json` should look like this:

```
{   
    "name": "sample-http",   
    "version": "0.0.1",   
    "dependencies": {
    "google-cloud": "^0.58.2",
    "@google-cloud/compute": "^0.10.0"   
    } 
 }
```

Continuing forward, the next steps should look similar to the following:

1. Use the code in the [Snapshot Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.9.x/Snapshot#get) to load all the available snapshots. Use the same logic as you did where getting the disks
2. Get the snapshot’s [`creationTimeStamp`](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/snapshots/get#body.Snapshot.FIELDS.creation_timestamp) and calculate the difference in days
3. Create a variable that will get  the current date in **“DD-MM-YYYY”** format `var datetime = new Date().toLocaleDateString();` to use this as suffix for your new snapshots
4. Use this method `new_snapshot_name = new_snapshot_name.replace(/\//g, '-');` to replace all `/` with `-` to match regex `'(?:[a-z](?:[-a-z0-9]{0,61}[a-z0-9])?)'`
5. Use the [`getDisk(...)`](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/compute/0.10.x/Zone#getDisks) method to list all the disks and create snapshots of them

I did a little bit of coding and it worked for me. The function does everything you described in your question. You can find my [code example in GitHub](https://github.com/andrikosrikos/Google-Cloud-Functions/blob/master/Node.js/backupVMDiskSnapshot.js)

Comment: Amazing work Andrei. the code in github worked as expected.  and awesome explanation. Really impressed